# Building an app that has a different quiz q's between fragments, what do I use to keep a running score?

Tags: android

I've been tried implementing an interface as I can't extend to multiple classes. Am I going about this the right way?
I'd like to have the method increaseScore()

```
public increaseScore(){
        score++;
       }
```

Basically it's a 10 question quiz and at the end I would like the app to display their total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.
I'm going to assume you are learning Android and just trying to find the shortest path to learn. I will provide a few options simplest to most complex.

1. static variable inside the class that holds the score, you can easily increment and use in the end.
2. singleton class with game specific variables that need to remain available
3. SharedPreference class store and retrieve your variable using the simple xml built int tool that Android gives for free
4. Passing Int through bundle from fragment to fragment
5. SQLite local DB to store and retrieve with basic CRUD operations
6. Cloud hosted server with APIs to send and retrieve the score

Obviously it depends on your need and what you are trying to learn. If you want opinions on how to do it in a professional enterprise environment the answer will also vary.

If you are learning, I would recommend getting your hands dirty and using SQLite. However, if you just want to focus on learning UI for now and get it done, then just go with a simple static.

Happy coding.